# Simpler ways to generate a negative voltage?

Tags: power-supply

I was in need of negative voltage to generate a ramp signal. But I am using the single supply. I tried to generate negative voltage using the DC-DC converter, but I felt it is quite an expensive solution. So are there any simpler ideas to generate negative voltage with a single supply?

My specifications are:

- Power: 1W
- Regulation: 5%

Comment: Why does the ramp need to go negative?

Comment: I would like to generate a ramp waveform using rectangular waveform using the active integrator circuit.

Comment: What is "the active integrator circuit"?

Comment: I meant to say opamp integrator circuit!

Answer (score 4):

ICL7660 (and similar chips) are cheap and will easily generate a negative voltage.

Even cheaper, if you have a clock signal around you can use a CMOS buffer to drive a simple charge pump and get ~-3V from +5V. Maybe 5-10 cents in moderate volume.

Neither of those are suitable for generating 1W, more like 10mA or less but I'm not sure you really need 1W.

For **simplicity** nothing beats a DC-DC converter (one part, potentially), but cheap ones tend to have lousy (or no) regulation and can give higher than normal voltage with a light load, so read the specs carefully.

There are plenty of inductor based switching supplies that can generate your 1W at -5V, as just one example, the LM2576 but there are many others.